# How to apply a defined function of format to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, format, user-defined-functions

I have multiple data frames (df, df1, df2,...) I want to apply my defined format and then export them to Excel (Excel-file, Excel-file1, Excel-file2,...)

I think of creating a defined function of formatting and applying it to my data frames but I do not know how to do about this.
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'N:\Excel-file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

```
# Skip one row to insert a defined header, turn off the default header, and remove index
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

# The xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# The default format of the workbook
workbook.formats[0].set_font_size(12)
workbook.formats[0].set_align('right')

# Header format
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'border': 0})
header_format.set_font_size(14)
header_format.set_align('center')

# Write the column headers with the defined format
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

# Export the Excel file
writer.close()
```

The defined function looks like below

```
    def format(df, file_name):
        with pd.ExcelWriter(r'file_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
            workbook = writer.book
            worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
            workbook.formats[0].set_font_size(12)
            workbook.formats[0].set_align('right')
            header_format = workbook.add_format({
            'bold': True,
            'border': 0})
            header_format.set_font_size(14)
            header_format.set_align('center')
            for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
                worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)


df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
  format(df, f"Excel-file{i+1}.xlsx")
```

The error is the format function only is applied to the df6 and I got 1 Excel file named "file_name". Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: if the code you've given is the formatting and saving you want to do, you just have to wrap it into a function that takes a filename and a data frame as an argument, and call that function on your 4 data frames, or am I missing something?

Comment: @FlorentMonin Sorry for not explaining my issue clearly. Please see my edited question. I did wrap into a function but ran into the error "format() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) iterates the dataframe, on which it is called, by rows (or by columns) and applies provided transformation and returns one result per row (or column). The transformation logic should consider this fact and should process it as if it is individual row (or column). Per your source code above, you seem to be applying the logic to entire dataframe (`df1`)  on which `apply()` is called.

I assume your problem statement is that you have multiple data frames (df, df1, df2,...) and you want to export them to individual Excel files by applying some common transformation logic.

You can collect them into a list and process them individually in a loop. Since `format()` does not return any results (i.e. not transforms the list element), the old fashioned iteration using `for` loop should be the way to go about it. Also, consider using `with` syntax for auto file resource handling to avoid memory leak or orphan file handlers.

```py
def format(df, file_name):
  with pd.ExcelWriter(r'file_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    workbook.formats[0].set_font_size(12)
    workbook.formats[0].set_align('right')
    header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'border': 0})
    header_format.set_font_size(14)
    header_format.set_align('center')
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)


df_list = [df1, df2, df3, ...]

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
  format(df, f"Excel-file{i+1}.xlsx")
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer. The idea of putting all data frames into a list and process them individually in a loop is great. But for some reason, when I try the script, the format function only is applied to the last df and I got 1 Excel file of that df only

Comment: Please update your question with the new source code and highlight the problem you are facing.

Comment: Issue is hard coded filename in `with pd.ExcelWriter(r'file_name.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer`. Replace it with `file_name`.

Comment: If replace it with file_name, there is an empty Excel file named "file_name"

Comment: Did you try `with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:`? Please update question with source code.

Comment: Hey, the edit queue is full so I cannot update the script now. But yes, I did try "with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:", there is an empty Excel file named "file_name"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248688/discussion-between-azhar-khan-and-sophie-pham).